# Is cx_Oracle 7.3.0 compatible with Python 3.10?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I need to upgrade to the latest version Python 3.10.1 but I already have a cx_Oracle version 7.3.0 running along with a Python 3.8.2.

Is cx_Oracle 7.3.0 compatible with Python 3.10 ?
Or do I need to also upgrade the cx_Oracle to the latest version 8.3 ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that we want questions whose answers will still be useful years later. That's very much not the case here -- if the answer is "no" today, it's unlikely to _stay_ "no" indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

According to [their Release Notes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes.html#releasenotes) I would say that `cx_Oracle` does not *officially* support Python 3.10 until Version 8.3

> **Version 8.3 (November 2021)**
>
> 1. Updated embedded ODPI-C to version 4.3.0.
> 2. **Added official support for Python 3.10.**
> 3. Support for dequeuing messages from Oracle Transactional Event Queue (TEQ) queues was restored.
> 4. Corrected calculation of attribute `MessageProperties.msgid`. Note that the attribute is now also read only.
> 5. Binary integer variables now explicitly convert values to integers (since implicit conversion to integer has become an error in Python 3.10) and values that are not int, float or decimal. Decimal are explicitly rejected.
> 6. Improved samples and test suite.

Version 7.3 only claims official support through Python 3.8.

Comment: Keep in mind, too, that Version 7.3 was released before Python 3.10 (or even Python 3.9) *existed*, so it couldn't claim support. That doesn't mean it *won't* work, only that it wasn't *verified* to work. Whether it *is* compatible is a different question than whether it *claims* to be compatible. Upgrading cx_Oracle would be ideal, but simply testing your code with Python 3.10 first would be worthwhile. ("Added official support for..." doesn't necessarily mean they actually *did* anything to fix a lack of support; they may have just run their test suite with Python 3.10 and found no issues.)

Comment: There was one minor change that was made to add support for Python 3.10 -- but it was merely to silence a warning, if I remember correctly. In any case, no testing has been performed with Python 3.10 and cx_Oracle 7.3 -- so you're on your own there!